# Reactjs positioning the view relative to other view

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have background of Mobile development, there we draw the layout relative to other layouts.
EX: Button A and Button B
I can position button B, right or left or top to button A, by referencing the ID of A

is there any way to achieve in reactjs? to display button B, relative to button A, by referencing to ID of A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo class, it has 'start' 'below' and 'end' buttons to change the positioning, A sample example of change positioning of view relative to other view.

```
/**
 * This is the testing class
 */


export default class DemoComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.firstRef = React.createRef();
        this.secondRef = React.createRef();
        this.thirdRef = React.createRef();

        this.onClickStart = this.onClickStart.bind(this)
        this.onClickBelow = this.onClickBelow.bind(this)
        this.onClickLast = this.onClickLast.bind(this)

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const first = this.firstRef.current;
        const second = this.secondRef.current;
        const third = this.thirdRef.current;

        const firstReact = first.getBoundingClientRect();
        let secondReact = second.getBoundingClientRect();
        const thirdreact = third.getBoundingClientRect();


        let top = firstReact.top + firstReact.height;
        let left = firstReact.left + firstReact.width / 2 + secondReact.width / 2;
        second.style.top = `${top + 20}px`;
        second.style.left = `${left}px`;

      //  secondReact = second.getBoundingClientRect();

        top = firstReact.top 
        left = firstReact.left + (4*firstReact.width) ;
        third.style.top = `${top}px`;
        third.style.left = `${left}px`;


    }

    onClickStart(event){

        //TODO

    }
    onClickBelow(event){
        //TODO
      
    }
    onClickLast(event){

        const first = this.firstRef.current;
        const second = this.secondRef.current
        const firstReact = first.getBoundingClientRect();
        const secondReact = second.getBoundingClientRect();

        const top = firstReact.top 
        const left = firstReact.left + firstReact.width  + 20;
        second.style.top = `${top }px`;
        second.style.left = `${left}px`;
    }

  

    render() {

        return (

            <div>

                <_row >
                  
                  <_button onClick={this.onClickStart}> start </_button>
                  <_button onClick={this.onClickBelow}> below </_button>
                  <_button onClick={this.onClickLast}> end </_button>


                </_row>
                <_parent id="first" ref={this.firstRef} value='first' name='first'>
                    First
                </_parent>

                <_child id="second" ref={this.secondRef} value='second' name='second'>
                    Second
                </_child>

                <_child id="third" ref={this.thirdRef} value='third' name='third'>
                    Third
                </_child>

            </div>

        )
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Web development is slightly different. You don't reference the ID of an element to another element to position them. You just position them the way you want them to.

For example, if you want to position Button A at left of Button B, place Button A at the top like this

```
<div>
  <ButtonA />
  <ButtonB />
</div>
```

ButtonB doesn't know ButtonA is on the left but it knows something is on the left. There's more to it honestly (like grids, flexboxes, etc) but I can't explain how the entire html/jsx and css works in one go so that's the simplest explanation I can give to you. I hope it somehow answer your question.

Here's a working sample, try to run it.

```html
<h3>Button A is at the left</h3>
<div>
 <button>Button A</button>
 <button>Button B</button>
</div>
<br /><br />

<h3>Button B is at the left</h3>
<div>
 <button>Button B</button>
 <button>Button A</button>
</div>
```

Comment: My problem is that I can place those two view in static manner,  for me button A have information of positioning button B